# Rails Ajax -> Sinatra -> Amazon API and back

Tags: ruby, ajax, sinatra

I'm not sure that I really understand how Sinatra works.

I'd like to get some products from Amazon using their API, in my Rails app. But HTTP requests are blocking the IO. I got the tip to create a Sinatra app and make an Ajax request to there instead.

**Ajax**: (From my Rails app)

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://sinatra.mydomain.com",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

**Sinatra app**: (I also make use of the Sinatra-synchrony gem)

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/synchrony'
require 'erb'
require 'rest-client'
require 'amazon_product'

Sinatra::Synchrony.overload_tcpsocket!

get '/' do  
  req = AmazonProduct["us"]
  req.configure do |c|
    c.key    = "KEY"
    c.secret = "SECRET"
    c.tag    = "TAG"
  end
  req << { :operation    => 'ItemSearch',
           :search_index => "DVD",
           :response_group => %w{ItemAttributes Images},
           :keywords => "nikita",
           :sort => "" }
  resp = req.get
  @item = resp.find('Item').shuffle.first

  erb :layout, :locals => { :amazon_product => @item }
end
```

**Layout.erb**: (renders fine if I go to this Url in the browser)

```
<%= amazon_product %>
```

---

**Problem**:

My Ajax response is a `200 OK` but with an empty response.
I'm can't figure out what's wrong. Please advise.

Comment: Is it your real amazon key? I think it's worth hiding..

Comment: i guess that your setup will have the same issues that you had with your rails application. the concurrent/evented io of synchrony will only work if you are using event-machine related gems, where rest-client is none of those as far as i know.

Comment: I understand, I might fix that later. Although it frees up my Rails IO. Either way, I need the ajax response to work.

Comment: so did you inspect all the variables you are using? what is their value? did you try using the ruby debugger or pry?

Comment: sinatra-synchrony patches the TCP socket (though it doesn't support SSL). You should check how the Amazon lib talks to the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you've faced with ajax 'cross-domain security' problem. Try to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) (JSON with padding).

Change your sinatra `get` handler:

```
get '/' do  
  req = AmazonProduct["us"]
  req.configure do |c|
    c.key    = KEY
    c.secret = SECRET
    c.tag    = TAG
  end
  req << { :operation    => 'ItemSearch',
           :search_index => "DVD",
           :response_group => %w{ItemAttributes Images},
           :keywords => "nikita",
           :sort => "" }
  resp = req.get
  @item = resp.find('Item').shuffle.first

  content_type :json
  callback = params.delete('callback') # jsonp
  json = @item.to_json

  if callback
    content_type :js
    response = "#{callback}(#{json})" 
  else
    content_type :json
    response = json
  end
  response
end
```

And change your **Ajax** request:

```
$.getJSON("http://address_of_sinatra?callback=?",
  function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Or you can add `dataType: 'jsonp'` to your `$.ajax` request.
After that you should see `data` object in js debugger (at least it's working in my case :D )